# Problems when closing and reopening a JFrame that uses a SwingWorker to send and receive messages

Tags: java, swing, sockets, swingworker

I am developing a messaging application with sockets. I have an initial `JFrame` that allows the user to choose a contact to connect to, and lets them choose if they'd like to be the client or the server. When they make this choice, it calls a method in which creates the chat window frame, and also uses a `SwingWorker` to initialise a connection, create an action listner on the send buton of the chat window so that it sends messages when pressed, and creates a `SocketListener` that is always listening while the window is open.

This works just fine, however if I close the chat window and then reopen it by choosing server or client again, nothing happens - the frame loads up however I cannot send any messages on it.

I'm not sure what the problem is here, could it be that i'm not disposing of the swing worker or the frame properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Here is the relevent code for this:

```
public static void server() {
    JButton server = new JButton();
    server.setText("Server");

    server.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String name = nameChoice;
            String ip = ipChoice;
            String port = portChoice;

            try {
                server2(port);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(server);
}

public static void server2(String port) throws Exception {
    gui.frame();

    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            sockets.serverSetup(port);
            gui.sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String msg = gui.newMsg.getText();
                    gui.newMsg.setText(null);
                    try {
                        sockets.sendMsg(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            while(gui.open==true) {
                sockets.receiveMsg();
            }
            sockets.closeConnection();
            System.out.println("Closed");
            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

### `network`

```
    package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Vector;

public class network {

    static ServerSocket s;
    static Socket s1;
    static OutputStream s1out;
    static DataOutputStream dos;
    static InputStream s1in;

    static chatWindowScreen gui = new chatWindowScreen();

    static String st;

    public static Vector sentVec = new Vector();
    public static Vector receivedVec = new Vector();

    public static Vector messages = new Vector();

    public static void serverSetup(String port) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Test");
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
        s = new ServerSocket(portInt);
        s1 = s.accept();
        System.out.println("Server set up");
        //sendMsg("Hi");
    }

    public static void clientSetup(String port, String ip) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Test");
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
        s1 = new Socket(ip, portInt);
        System.out.println("Client set up");
        //receiveMsg();
    }

    public static void closeConnection() throws IOException {
        dos.close();
        s1out.close();
        s1.close();
    }

    public static void sendMsg(String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Test");

        s1out = s1.getOutputStream();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s1out);
        dos.writeUTF(message);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String t1 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        message = t1 + " - " + message;

        sentVec.add(message);
        receivedVec.add("");

        messages.add(message);

        gui.sent.setText("Sent \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < sentVec.size(); i++) {
            gui.sent.append(sentVec.get(i) + "\n");
        }

        gui.received.setText("Received \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < receivedVec.size(); i++) {
            gui.received.append(receivedVec.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("complete");
    }

    public static void receiveMsg() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Test");

        s1in = s1.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s1in);
        st = (dis.readUTF());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String t1 = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        st = t1 + " - " + st;

        receivedVec.add(st);
        sentVec.add("");

        messages.add(st);

        gui.received.setText("Received \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < receivedVec.size(); i++) {
            gui.received.append((String) receivedVec.get(i) + "\n");
        }

        gui.sent.setText("Sent \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < sentVec.size(); i++) {

            gui.sent.append((String) sentVec.get(i) + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static Vector getSentVec() {
        return sentVec;
    }

    public static Vector getReceivedVec() {
        return receivedVec;

    }
}
```

### `chatWindowScreen`

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;

public class chatWindowScreen {

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    static JTextArea sent;
    static JTextArea received;
    static JTextArea newMsg;
    static JButton sendButton;
    public static String msg;
    static boolean open = true;

    static network sockets = new network();

    public static boolean close = false;

    public void frame() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("GUI opened");

        frame.setTitle("Messaging Application");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

                System.out.println("Closed");
                panel.removeAll();
                open=false;
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
        });

        sentMsg();
        receivedMsg();
        msgBox();
        sendBtn();
        save();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void sentMsg() {
        sent = new JTextArea(15, 20);
        sent.setText("Sent" + "\n");
        sent.setLineWrap(true);
        sent.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(sent, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        panel.add(pane);
    }

    public static void receivedMsg() {
        received = new JTextArea(15, 20);
        received.setText("Received" + "\n");
        received.setEditable(false);
        received.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane pane1 = new JScrollPane(received, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        panel.add(pane1);
    }

    public static void msgBox() {
        newMsg = new JTextArea(1, 15);
        newMsg.setText("");
        newMsg.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane pane2 = new JScrollPane(newMsg, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        panel.add(pane2);
    }

    public static void sendBtn() {

        sendButton = new JButton();
        sendButton.setText("Send!");

        /*sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                msg = newMsg.getText();
                newMsg.setText(null);

                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        sockets.sendMsg(msg);
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                worker.execute();

                try {
                    sockets.sendMsg(msg);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                msg = null;

            }
        });*/

        panel.add(sendButton);
    }

    public static void save(){

        JButton save = new JButton();
        save.setText("Save Conversation");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveToFile save = new saveToFile();
            }
        });

        panel.add(save);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.